# Static Data Input Row for Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'd like a static data input row in my Excel spreadsheet. This row would allow the user to submit a row of data and press Enter or a Submit button to have the row added to either the bottom of the sheet or the top. The final location of the row of data isn't a big deal. How would I do this? Searching SO and Google have come up empty unless I am using the wrong terms.

Comment: Do you prefer it like a row or like a form for data entry?

Comment: I would prefer it to be a row near the top of the spreadsheet. I tried the Data Form and that isn't going to work when I transfer the Spreadsheet to my Android tablet for daily use.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you try to find a solution for data entry. Microsoft's solution for that in Microsoft Excel is to use a data form (found under the `Data` tab). [Here is a tutorial from Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Simplify-data-entry-with-a-data-form-00bfc75e-f675-46ad-8703-291fc03e4d77?ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US).